# Não salva a foto na pasta do Android

Tags: java, android

Estou com um problema para salvar a foto na pasta de imagens do Android. Simplesmente ele não salva a foto, ou seja, nem executa o `TRY` do `ActivityResult`. 
Até chega a colocar no `ImageView`:

```
// CAPTURAR FOTO BOTÃO TIRAR FOTO

public void tirarFoto (View view) throws IOException {
    SimpleDateFormat nomeFoto = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyy_hh-MM-ss");
    caminhoFoto =  new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), nomeFoto + ".jpg");
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    System.out.println(caminhoFoto);
    System.out.println(nomeFoto);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}


//JOGA NO ACTIVITY RESULT
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Request Imagem
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null) {
                    Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                    if (bundle != null) {
                    // Captura o ImageView
                     ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_camera);

                     // Redimensiona a Foto
                     BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions =
                     new BitmapFactory.Options();
                     bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                     BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
                     caminhoFoto.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);

                     // Salva a imagem no ImageView
                     Bitmap img = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
                     iv.setImageBitmap(img);

                     // SALVA A IMAGEM NO APLICATIVO

                     try {
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

                        byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();

                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(caminhoFoto);
                        fos.write(bytes);
                        fos.close();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Salvou foto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     } catch (Exception e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }

                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "RESULTADO CANCELADO:\n" + data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

**Resolvido:** O problema era declarar a permissão de escrita no `ANDROID MANIFEST`,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```